# JS + onmouseover + onmouseout

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, fullpage

Вопрос по js.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});

document.body.onmouseover = document.body.onmouseout = handler;

function handler(event){
    if(event.type == "mouseover")
    {
        event.target.style.display = "none";
    }
    if(event.type == "mouseout")
    {
        event.target.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Сайт у меня разбит на секции. И при скролле сразу переходит на следующую секцию.
На каждой секции есть `div.mask` который затемнен `position: absolute; height,width: 100%;` Нужно было сделать так, что при "активной" секции `$('.mask')` становится `display:none`.

Если в условие `handler` вместо объекта `event` поставить `$('.mask')`, перестает работать сама функция. Т. е. `onmouse*` не работает. Т.е. вот так: `$('.mask').target.style.display = "none";`

Как при `hover`-e на секцию сделать так, чтобы `.mask` исчезала? Причем в первой секции `<header>` она не работала?

Хочу добится вот такого эффекта: http://wearevisualanimals.com/
только без лишних плагинов и усложнений

Answer (score 2):

А зачем вам такие усложнения с ховером? Если вы используете этот плагин http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage, то можно обойтись вообще без дополнительных скриптов.

Активный слайд имеет класс `active`. Если маска лежит прямо внутри слайда, то в css напишите:

```
.mask{
    display:block;
}

.active .mask{
    display:none;
}
```

## Если нужна анимация:

```
.mask{
    display:block;
    pointer-events: none; /*чтобы маска не перехватывала клик*/
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.active .mask{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

## Рабочий пример

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage();

});
```

```css
.mask {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.active .mask {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.9.2/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">

  <div class=section>
    <div class=mask></div>PAGE1</div>

  <div class=section>
    <div class=mask></div>PAGE2</div>

</div>
```

## Решение с `hover`

Если вы все-таки хотите убирать маску при наведении мыши, то это тоже легче сделать только на css:

```
.mask{
    display:block;
}

.section:hover .mask{
    display:none;
}
```

Пример с анимацией:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage();

});
```

```css
.mask {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.section:hover .mask {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.9.2/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">

  <div class=section>
    <div class=mask></div>PAGE1</div>

  <div class=section>
    <div class=mask></div>PAGE2</div>

</div>
```

Всякое решение, использующее положение мыши, плохо тем, что когда курсор мыши уходит со страницы, то маска появляется снова, даже на активном слайде.

## Решение на JavaScript

Ну и еще один пример, для ознакомления, как это сделать все-таки на JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage();

 
  $('#fullpage .section').hover(function(){
      $(this).find('.mask').fadeToggle()
  })
  
});
```

```css
.mask {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.9.2/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">

  <div class=section>
    <div class=mask></div>PAGE1</div>

  <div class=section>
    <div class=mask></div>PAGE2</div>

</div>
```

Comment: С css нельзя сжелать, ибо прерывания как-то не так работают, и экран начинает просто моргать.

Comment: И если делать без ховера, то как можно активный экран отслеживать? Остальное опробую и отпишу, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

С `body` ивент видет себя не предсказуемо. поэтому использовал `document`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();

});

document.onmouseover = document.onmouseout = handler;

function handler(event){
    if(event.type == "mouseover")
    {
        event.target.style.display = "none";
    }
    if(event.type == "mouseout")
    {
        event.target.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.9.2/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage" style="background:red;width:50vw;height:50vh"></div>
```

Comment: Я только не могу понять, в чем смысл скрывать всю страницу?

Comment: а какой элемент вам нужно скрыть?